# Bug of fast scroll to bottom of GridView in Android

Tags: android

When I fast scroll of GridView to bottom and I see the last row, GridView'll jump up on several rows.

If I scroll slow, It's work fine.

How to fix it? I've never have this bug before.

Comment: It happens when scroll state is SCROLL_STATE_FLING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but if you set overScrollMode = "never", you'll get this bug on HTC Sensation and Motorola.

Comment: Same on a Huawei with 2.3.5